# PHP-FPM SuExecUserGroup not working

Tags: apache-2.2, php-fpm, gentoo, suexec

I have installed php, apache, and fastcgi_handler by:

```
emerge dev-lang/php www-apache/mod_fastcgi_handler
```

I managed to make it work by updating the relevant lines in /etc/apache2/modules.d/70_mod_php5.conf

to:

```
# AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php .php5 .phtml
# AddHandler application/x-httpd-php-source .phps
AddHandler fcgi:/var/run/php-fpm.socket .php .php5
```

and /etc/conf.d/apache2 to

```
APACHE2_OPTS="-D DEFAULT_VHOST -D INFO -D SSL -D SSL_DEFAULT_VHOST -D SUEXEC -D LANGUAGE -D PHP5 -D FASTCGI_HANDLER"
```

In my document root, I have the following file to verify the installation:

```
<?php
echo '<pre>';
var_dump(exec('whoami'));
var_dump(php_sapi_name());
```

I then have the following vhost:

```
<IfDefine DEFAULT_VHOST>
        <VirtualHost localhost:80>
                ServerName local.testdomain.com
                ServerAlias local.testdomain.com
                SuExecUserGroup foobar foobar
                DocumentRoot "/home/foobar/workspace/local.testdomain.com"
                <Directory "/home/foobar/workspace/local.testdomain.com">
                        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
                        AllowOverride All
                        Order allow,deny
                        Allow from all
                </Directory>
        </VirtualHost>
</IfDefine>
```

Which results to: 501 Error

```
[Wed Jul 10 01:52:10 2013] [error] [client ::1] (13)Permission denied: access to / denied (filesystem path '/home/foobar/workspace/') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path
```

Moving the document root outside the user directory, the test.php seems to be executed properly, however I get this result:

```
string(6) "nobody"
string(8) "fpm-fcgi"
```

I'm expecting it to be:

```
string(6) "foobar"
string(8) "fpm-fcgi"
```

My assumption is that if I could get SuExec to work properly, it could traverse the user's directory without a problem.

In my deduction, this confirms that PHP-FPM is working correctly, however this directive: " **SuExecUserGroup foobar foobar**" doesn't. SuExec is surely working because I get the following line in the logs:

```
[Wed Jul 10 02:09:47 2013] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
```

I hope somebody could point to me what am I missing, and how I may possibly fix it.

Thanks in advance.

I'm using Gentoo btw.

Answer (score 1):

With PHP-FPM, SuExec is no longer needed if you want to change the uid of your PHP processes.

You can use the directives 'user' and 'group' of the [php-fpm configuration file](https://web.archive.org/web/20130128161839/http://php-fpm.org/wiki/Configuration_File) to perform the same thing.